# rails axlsx format table header diagonally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, axlsx

I am using the ruby on rails axlsx gem to render my excel. 
Now I want to style the text so that it shows up diagonally as shown in the sample image attached.
I am not sure where or how to set this alignment feature in the code.
Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alignment: {:textRotation => 60}
```

That did it for me.
I managed to find a similar issue from the axlsx github page:
https://github.com/randym/axlsx/issues/110

I wasn't able to locate it in the docs.

The complete code can be implemented as follows:

```
my_style {
alignment: {:textRotation => 60, horizontal: :center, vertical: :center, wrap_text: true},
}
sheet.add_row(headers, style: styles[:my_style], height: height)
```

Comment: please add more information to this answer, and explain why it should help